# Is it possible to delete all selected records in the result of search layout?

Tags: administration

Is it possible to delete all selected records in the result of search layout? 
Like Mass Delete in search view.

Example: select customer object tab and search for all by pressing GO button and in the result selected all check box. Then clicked del like it ask for confirmation but it was deleting only one record at a time.

Answer (score 1):

What you are navigating to is not a technically called a 'search layout', it is a list view.

A quick way to allow mass deletions of records from a list view is using the [Mass Delete appExchange package](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YuDEAU) from Salesforce Labs

Alternatively, you can add a custom button which uses the Ajax toolkit to perform the delete operation on the selected records.

Comment: There are checkboxes for every record, for what?

Comment: It's for mass editing, check the rows and inline edit a field of one of those rows and it will give you the option to update the field on all the rows. P.S thank you @Mark I had a customer ask about this exact question this week